# How is New Horizons powered?

Tags: power, new-horizons

My understanding is that New Horizons has an RTG on board, which generates electricity for it's systems.

**How and when was the RTG manufactured, and how does it work? How exactly does New Horizons distribute power around the spacecraft?**

Comment: The answer is provided in: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/what-pushes-new-horizons-towards-pluto

Comment: I asked this question as a place for that well - written and relevant answer to reside. @Hobbes