# How many nuclear fission reactors have been launched into space? How many are still there?

Tags: debris, safety, russia, nuclear

I remember [p@Hobbes's answer to *Which countries have built RTGs and used them in Earth orbit and/or beyond?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27423/12102) mentioning that the US has put one nuclear fission reactor in space, and that not much was known about Russia's program.

The Bloomberg article [NASA Is Bringing Back Cold War-Era Atomic Rockets to Get to Mars; Nuclear-powered spacecraft would cut travel time to the Red Planet](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-02-15/nasa-is-bringing-back-cold-war-era-atomic-rockets-to-get-to-mars) says:

> Russia’s Rosatom Corp. has said it plans this year to test a prototype nuclear engine for a spacecraft that can go to Mars. **Russia so far has led research in the field and has deployed more than 30 fission reactors in space, according to the World Nuclear Association**. China aims to use atomic-powered shuttles as part of its space exploration plans through 2045, according to state Xinhua News Agency.

I'd never heard of the "World Nuclear Association" before today.

**Question:** So is the answer to "How many nuclear fission reactors have been launched into space?" then 31? The answer to "How many still there?" 31 as well?

**note:** don't confuse fission reactor with alpha-decay-based RTGs.

---

[image: "A mock-up of a full size Nuclear Engine for Rocket Vehicles Application, or NERVA, in 1967." Source: Bettmann Archives via Getty Images. https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-02-15/nasa-is-bringing-back-cold-war-era-atomic-rockets-to-get-to-mars]

**above:** "A mock-up of a full size Nuclear Engine for Rocket Vehicles Application, or NERVA, in 1967." Source: Bettmann Archives via Getty Images. From [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2018-02-15/nasa-is-bringing-back-cold-war-era-atomic-rockets-to-get-to-mars)

Comment: At least one very famous one is not still in orbit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosmos_954

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's great news, [apparently only 31 more to go...](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27909/12102)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [a new list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nuclear_power_systems_in_space) that has a better breakdown of Russian nuclear power systems in space. It lists 32 BES-5 thermoelectric reactors, 2 Topaz reactors, 5 RTGs and 2 '2 kWe' reactors.

At least 6 of those have reentered. The Wikipedia article does not give current status for many of these missions. [Its source](http://www.space4peace.org/ianus/npsm3.htm) lists those missions as still in orbit. So 36 reactors and 5 RTGs have been flown, 6 of those have reentered for a total of 31 reactors and 4 RTGs still in orbit.

Comment: The Wikipedia article does not give current status for many of these missions, which is why I declined to put a current number in my answer. List answers are not a good fit for SE as the next launch of orbital decay will make the answer incorrect again.

Comment: Ya I understand. I can add "roughly" to the question if you'd like. I'm only interested in the quantities, not any kind of list. It's pretty amazing to thing that almost a half-dozen kW-sized nuclear reactors have reentered the atmosphere. I had no idea!

Comment: "have been flown". Shouldn't you add "by Russia" ? Just Apollo program alone flew more that those 5 RTG.

Comment: Already in the first sentence. 'breakdown of Russian nuclear power systems'

Comment: I've just asked [What was the most recent launch of a nuclear reactor, and what are the current barriers to launching the next one?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34139/12102)