# Could I claim an asteroid if I landed on it?

Tags: asteroid, law, international-politics

Could I claim an Asteroid if I landed on it? If so, could I have a nuclear reactor on it for a power generator?

Comment: It's okay with me, except on any of the [asteroids named after rock stars](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28736/7982) (discussion of the [announcement](https://youtu.be/o2vo6VR51eA) and clip of the asteroid itself).

Comment: Have you got a flag?

Comment: i can make one :)

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_real_estate for a discussion of the relevant treaties.

Comment: You may try to claim it but there is no authority that would registrate your claim and no jurisdicition protecting your claim.

Comment: If you are capable of landing on (docking with?) an Asteroid and bringing a nuclear reactor you probably have the backing as well as permission of major nations or are influential enough to lobby for it. You would probably have a good reason to go there. What are thinking you could do with it? Self sufficiency won't be possible and asteroid mining probably can get permissions equivalent to ownership of the resources extracted but not Sovereignty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if it is true that "*In Space, No One Can Hear You Claim.*"

You can claim it, then you can announce your claim, but what happens next in terms of recognition, and *enforcement* is another matter. What will you do about space-bourne [claim-jumpers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/claim_jumper) and space pirates?

Can you put a nuclear reactor on it, sure! You can copy the designs of the [kilopower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilopower) reactor of NASA or DIY it. However, "Can I launch a nuclear reactor" is a very different question and that needs a more nuanced answer, though "probably not easily" is a good first approximation. You might do better against protesters if you launch from the Ocean if you can find a spot; [Where is the San Marco Launch Platform now?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33182/12102)

Not to suggest that there haven't been nuclear reactors launched already. See answers to [How many nuclear fission reactors have been launched into space? How many are still there?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27908/12102) for more on that.