# Where is the San Marco Launch Platform now?

Tags: launch-site, italian-space-agency

@Hobbes's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31868/12102) to a question about *gregarious rockets* mentions the San Marco platform of the [Broglio_Space_Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broglio_Space_Center).

That Wikipedia lists the following coordinates: [2°56′18″S 40°12′45″E](https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=Broglio_Space_Center&params=2_56_18_S_40_12_45_E_) and that link gives the decimal values as `-2.938333, 40.2125`. Typing "*2.938333S, 40.2125E*" into google maps does take me (just barely) off the coast of Ngomeni, Kenya, but images just shows blue water, no converted oil drilling platform.

Is this a portable platform that's moored somewhere else? Are the coordinates incorrect? Has it been taken away for good? Are google maps images just old and it really is at these coordinates? Something else?

> The San Marco launch platform complex was in use from March 1964 to March 1988, with a total of 27 launches, primarily sounding rockets including the Nike Apache, Nike Tomahawk, Arcas and Black Brant launchers. Low payload weight orbital launches were also made, using the solid-propellant Scout rocket (in its B, D and G subvariants). The first satellite specifically for X-ray astronomy, Uhuru, was launched from San Marco on a Scout B rocket on 12 December 1970.
>
> The ground station is in use and continues to track NASA, ESA and Italian satellites. **However, the two platforms fell into disrepair during the 1990s. Recently, the Italian Space Agency has conducted a feasibility study to reactivate it for the Russian launcher START-1.**

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this? http://www.astronautix.com/s/sanmarco.html

Comment: @AlexHajnal *By 2003 the platforms were in a very decrepit state and the scrap yard beckoned.*

Comment: Yea, well there's only so much you can tell from 1.7 meter/pixel imagery.  It looked like it might've survived; guess not.  :^(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What appears to be the launch platform can be [found here](https://mapper.acme.com/?ll=-2.94173,40.21404&z=15&t=SL&marker0=-2.93833%2C40.21250%2CBroglio%20Space%20Center).  The marker ~500 meters to the NNW of the launch platform is where Wikipedia claims the site is.  Based on the image quality I'd guess the satellite photo was taken sometime in the 2010s; the citation on the ArcGIS online map gives the date as 2017<sup>1</sup>.  If that's true, it's held up pretty well!  ([Unfortunately not](http://www.astronautix.com/s/sanmarco.html))

**Satellite view (2017-03-20)**  (north is up)

<sup>Left-to-right: **Control platform** (1.1 km from launch platform), **Unknown** (600 m from launch platform), **Launch platform**</sup>
[image: Satellite image of San Marco platforms]
<sup>Source: Esri via [Acme Mapper](https://mapper.acme.com/?ll=-2.94173,40.21404&z=15&t=SL&marker0=-2.93833%2C40.21250%2CBroglio%20Space%20Center) / OpenStreetMap Sweden<sup>3</sup>

The dimesions of the launch platform are 90 meters × 30 meters</sup>

**Sea-level view of launch platform (1974)**  (looking north-west)
[image: Photo of San Marco platform from the sea]
<sup>Source: [NASA](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/ariel5/ariel5_launch.html) courtesy John Ives and John Raymont via Wikipedia, public domain</sup>

**Sea-level view of control platform (1974)**  (looking north-west)
[image: Control platform from the sea (1974)]
<sup>Source: [NASA](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/ariel5/ariel5_launch.html) courtesy John Ives and John Raymont, public domain</sup>

<sup>1</sup> From the [ArcGIS.com map](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fservices.arcgisonline.com%2Farcgis%2Frest%2Fservices%2FWorld_Imagery%2FMapServer&source=sd):
**Date imaged**: 2017-03-20, **Resolution**<sup>2</sup>: 0.50 meters, **Accuracy**: 10.20 meters,
**Satellite**: [WorldView2](https://dg-cms-uploads-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/document/file/98/WorldView2-DS-WV2-rev2.pdf), **Source**: DigitalGlobe (Vivid)

"Date imaged" has been verified as correct.

<sup>2</sup> The image included above has been downsampled to ~1.67 meters per pixel.

<sup>3</sup> Tiles © Esri — Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community, Tiles courtesy of OpenStreetMap Sweden

Comment: Thanks, do you know "Where is the San Marco Launch Platform **now?**"

Comment: I can't do any better than say where it likely was ca. 2010.  Sorry.

Comment: and you've estimated the date of the image "by eye"?

Comment: In my work I do a lot of interpretation of aerial imagery.  The resolution, quality, colors, etc. point to a post-2010 date in my opinion.  I'd give a margin of error of maybe -5,+8 years on my 2010 estimate, later being more likely.

Comment: I certainly like [your images better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkkJg.png) than what I can see in google maps. Nearby [trees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3eRk.png) on land and [clouds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z42b.png) over the [water](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBrzi.png) have a few meter resolution, but for some reason in the area of the platform the resolution becomes much much worse, [almost as if it's been deliberately blurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiPsZ.jpg) but maybe it's just algorithmic blending of areal photography over land and old satellite photography over the water.

Comment: @uhoh That's because it has been deliberately blurred.  Google [feathers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feathering) the edges of their satellite imagery around coastlines over a shaded relief map of the seabed based on bathymetric data .

Comment: my goodness I see what you mean! This is just north of Taipei: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eM49x.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aBoz.jpg

Comment: @uhoh I found a citation for that sat image giving 2017 as the date, see the answer.  Knowing how these things go that date is either accurate or the image was likely taken in mid-to-late 2016.

Comment: Great, that date is described as the date the image was taken, or the date it might have been copyrighted, or the date it was incorporated into the database?

Comment: Can't say for sure; the original citation only says "DATE" (twice).  In [this blog post](http://blog.digitalglobe.com/news/good-news-for-arcgis-users-you-now-have-access-to-the-premium-mosaic-layers-in-digitalglobe-basemap/) dated 29 June 2016, DigitalGlobe is touting their new partnership with Esri for their 0.5 meter imagery.  Personally, I'd believe the citation (with the caveat I gave earlier).  i.e. the date given is probably when it was imaged.

Comment: There are even better resolution images by DigitalGlobe:
https://imgur.com/a/GPcHhSp

Comment: @asdfex Is that image OK to repost here? What's its source/license?

Comment: @AlexHajnal It is available on https://platform.digitalglobe.com/maps-api/ (without a dedicated license for this viewer), the same images are available for use for OSM (tracing only). If we don't find another source with a better license I fear the answer is "no".